# How to display european calendar date and time. fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, date, fullcalendar

Using the latest version of fullcalendar, however can't find how to display european date and time. Currently it show american month/date, I would like to show date/month.

If anyone faced this issue let me know how to fix it.
[image]

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/)?

Comment: Sorry, I might wrongly explained my question, just added a printscreen of what should be changed

Comment: So basically, formatDate gives back a string, and I would like to make a change on calendar itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify this in the [columnFormat](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/columnFormat/), like so:

```
columnFormat: {
    month: 'ddd',    // Mon
    week: 'ddd d/M', // Mon 31/12
    day: 'dddd d/M'  // Monday 31/12
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I found it after searching for a format, really silly question and easy 25 points for you ;)

Comment: Thanks - I won't complain ;)